# Change style bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, abnt

I want to change the style of font for "References". I want the title of books and Articles stay in BOLD and don't in ITALIC BOLD how stay on my document.

My style stay:

KNUTH, D. E. ***The art of computer programming***, Volume 16: Fundamental Algorithms.
[S.l.]: Addison-Wesley, 1968.

I would like:

KNUTH, D. E. **The art of computer programming**, Volume 16: Fundamental Algorithms.
[S.l.]: Addison-Wesley, 1968.

---

I'm use the style ABNT-ALF 
\bibliographustyle{abnt-alf}

This is not my all code, however is possible see the part that I need help:

Main Document (with settings):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[brazil,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{abnt-alf}
\usepackage[alf]{abntcite}

\newcommand{\qcounts}{{\normalfont\textit{quadrat counts}}{}}
\newcommand{\q}{{\normalfont\textit{quadrat}}{}}
\newcommand{\qs}{{\normalfont\textit{quadrats}}{}}
\newcommand{\citrus}{{\normalfont\textit{Citrus}}{}}
\newcommand{\msc}{{\normalfont\textit{Morte Súbita dos Citrus}}{}}
\newcommand{\MSC}{\acronym{MSC}{}}
\newcommand{\geoR}{{\normalfont\textsf{geoR}}{}}
\newcommand{\geoRglm}{{\normalfont\textsf{geoRglm}}{}}
\newcommand{\splancs}{{\normalfont\textsf{splancs}}{}}
\title{Modelo autologístico para dados de citrus}

\author{
Fabio CORDEIRO 
\footnote{Programa de Pós-graduação em Engenharia Elétrica, 
 Pontifícia Universidade Católica de Minas Gerais. 
Caixa Postal 00000, CEP 81531-990, Belo Horizonte, Minas Gerais, Brasil. 
E-mail: fabioleandro@oucminas.br}\\
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{resumo} 

\section{Introducao}

Testando referencias \cite{knuth}

\section{metodologia}

\bibliographystyle{abnt-alf} 

\bibliography{bibliografia} %%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

My bibliography file:

```
@book{knuth,
    author = {Donald E. Knuth},
    title = {\textbf{The art of computer programming}, Volume 16: Fundamental Algorithms},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    year = {1968}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem or, at the very least, tell us what style you're using to create your bibliography.

Comment: Let me support lockstep's suggestion that you indicate, at the very least, which bibliography style you employ. BibTeX obtains all formatting-related directives from the bibliography style file that's specified via the, you guessed it, the command `\bibliographystyle{<somestyle>}`.

Comment: `abnt-alf.sty`, `abntcite.sty`, and `abnt-alf.bst` are not available on CTAN, so you need to provide a link to those files.

Comment: Fábio, I'm not sure if I understood your request, neither if my solution is robust enough, but you could copy `abnt-alf.bst` to a new file, say `abnt-fabio.bst`, edit line 2068 replacing `\emph` by `\textbf`, then change `\bibliographystyle{abnt-alf}` to `\bibliographystyle{abnt-fabio}`. I do not recommend to include formatting instructions directly in the `.bib` file, that's the `.bst` role. `:)`

Comment: Hello, Paulo Cereda,
Work perfectly. I do changes on new file based on "abnt-alf" like your say and was all okay.
Thanks very much

Comment: @FábioCordeiro: I'm glad it worked. `:)` In any case, please, consider trying henrique's answer below, since it's the "correct" way of doing it. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

With [**`abntcite`**](http://codigolivre.org.br/frs/?group_id=46) package, you can choose the emph style with the option `abnt-emphasize` during the package load with

```
\usepackage[alf,abnt-emphasize=bf]{abntcite}
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% to embed a .bib file in the source
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{knutha,
    author = {Donald E. Knuth},
    booktitle = {The art of computer programming},
    volume = {16},
    title = {Fundamental Algorithms},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    year = {1968}
}
@book{knuthb,
    author = {Donald E. Knuth},
    title = {The art of computer programming},
    subtitle = {Volume 16, Fundamental Algorithms},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    year = {1968}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[alf,abnt-emphasize=bf]{abntcite}

\begin{document}

Here's how I'd quote that book: \cite{knutha}; and here's (almost) how you asked for: \cite{knuthb}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: ABNTcite with abnt-emphasize=bf option]

Please refer to the documentation in the `abntex-doc-<version>.<zip>` (or `.tar.gz`, etc) file on the [project's page](http://codigolivre.org.br/frs/?group_id=46).