# Customize bst for shown year after Title

Tags: bibliographies, abnt

I'm need of change master thesis are shown. I'm used the ABNT-ALF with some modifications ex: abnt-my.bst.

I need that YEAR shown (date) after o TITLE and before of type.
However, such change not modify another types : (Article, Book, etc)

like stay:

CORDEIRO, F. L. R. **Representações neural e fuzzy de controle**. Dissertação (Mestrado) — Pontifícia Universidade Católica de Minas Gerais, Programa de Pós-graduação em Informática, 2010.

How it must be:

CORDEIRO, F. L. R. **Representações neural e fuzzy de controle**. 2010. Dissertação (Mestrado) — Pontifícia Universidade Católica de Minas Gerais, Programa de Pós-graduação em Informática.

My main document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[brazil,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{abnt-alf}
\usepackage[alf]{abntcite}

\newcommand{\qcounts}{{\normalfont\textit{quadrat counts}}{}}
\newcommand{\q}{{\normalfont\textit{quadrat}}{}}
\newcommand{\qs}{{\normalfont\textit{quadrats}}{}}
\newcommand{\citrus}{{\normalfont\textit{Citrus}}{}}
\newcommand{\msc}{{\normalfont\textit{Morte Súbita dos Citrus}}{}}
\newcommand{\MSC}{\acronym{MSC}{}}
\newcommand{\geoR}{{\normalfont\textsf{geoR}}{}}
\newcommand{\geoRglm}{{\normalfont\textsf{geoRglm}}{}}
\newcommand{\splancs}{{\normalfont\textsf{splancs}}{}}
\title{Modelo autologístico para dados de citrus}

\author{
Fabio CORDEIRO 
\footnote{Programa de Pós-graduação em Engenharia Elétrica, 
 Pontifícia Universidade Católica de Minas Gerais. 
Caixa Postal 00000, CEP 81531-990, Belo Horizonte, Minas Gerais, Brasil. 
E-mail: fabioleandro@oucminas.br}\\
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{resumo} 

\section{Introducao}

Testando referencias \cite{fabio}

\section{metodologia}

\bibliographystyle{abnt-alf} 

\bibliography{bibliografia} %%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

My bibliography file:

```
@MASTERSTHESIS{fabio,
author = {Anna Izabel J. Tostes},
title = {Representações neural e fuzzy de controle},
school = {Pontifícia Universidade Católica de Minas Gerais},
year = {2010}
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, as @PauloCereda has pointed out (in a comment to [Change style bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81989/change-style-bibliographies?rq=1)), you don't have to hack into the `.bst` file to accomplish this, since with [**`abntcite`**](http://codigolivre.org.br/frs/?group_id=46) package, you have several options  that can be chosen during the package load with

```
\usepackage[<option>]{abntcite}
```

Please refer to the documentation in the `abntex-doc-<version>.<zip>` file on the [project's page](http://codigolivre.org.br/frs/?group_id=46).

To accomplish what you're asking now, you just have to change `abnt-thesis-year`option to `both` with

```
\usepackage[abnt-thesis-year=both]{abntcite}
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% to embed a .bib file in the source
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MASTERSTHESIS{fabio,
author = {Anna Izabel J. Tostes},
title = {Representações neural e fuzzy de controle},
school = {Pontifícia Universidade Católica de Minas Gerais},
year = {2010}
}\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[alf,abnt-emphasize=bf,abnt-thesis-year=both]{abntcite}

\begin{document}

\cite{fabio}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: ABNTcite with abnt-thesis-year=both option]

(It's worth noting, however, that this might not be always correct, since what the ABNT aims here are those cases when the date of the public defense (the first `year`, next to the title) and the date of publication (the final `year`) are different. `abntcite` does not support these cases).

Comment: Thanks for answer.  The just thinks that I don't have certainty is the year in final. 
I think that standards of my University, don't have year in finale, then I think that need withdraw.

How can I do?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `abnt-thesis-year=title` instead of `both`. The default is `final`. Those are the three options for setting the year field in thesis entries. Check the table 4.3, section 4.2.2 on the [above mentioned documentation](http://codigolivre.org.br/frs/?group_id=46)

Comment: Glad it helped. You might consider to accept the answer (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852))